# Academic advantages of activity on SE

Tags: discussion

What are the (probable) academic advantages of having scientific activities on mathematics stack exchange?
For example, if someone gets large reputations and many badges, is there any chances for him/her to be invited to a related academic job?

Comment: I don't believe there are any. [See this.](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7552/9646) (You're very, very optimistic with your new sentence.)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi So, what are the motivations for being active in this community(other than just problem solving)?

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12991/10014

Comment: Short answer: there are none.

Comment: Short answer: There is an advantage, if you do a good work in writing good explanations in a certain topic, you might get your name out there before doing anything substantial. This has its advantages, but it largely depends on whether or not you can back this reputation with original research, and what sort of research community you belong to. The short answer, if so, there might be some marginal advantage, but not due to reputation or badges.

Comment: (Let me clarify my previous comment, in case it wasn't clear, the fact that you produce a lot of quality answers is what helps you to set up a name. Not the reputation or badges.)

Comment: Could be a disadvantage: if they see you asked SE to do your homework for you...

Comment: Related question (and my answer) on TeX SE meta: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3938/the-importance-for-getting-an-account/3947#3947

Comment: I had voted to close this, but on second thought it can be construed as being about the site.

Comment: @quid It is about the site. It is not "about the site within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)". I consider it a subsection of [Q12991](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12991/43351) in no need of separate discussion.

Comment: @Lord_Farin This feels somewhat contradictory. (Except if you think the other question is not on-topic either.) I disagree it is a part of the other question. And, instead think the other question is a precedent.

Comment: @quid A "furthermore" wouldn't have hurt, I guess. // I'll settle for indefinite disagreement.

Comment: I see a big disadvantage: The time I'm on SE, I don't spend on academic stuff.

Comment: You have something to show in terms of your ability to explain when writing answers, your skills in the subjects should show through your questions and answers, and that you can follow community rules and earn responsibilities. But there are also some qualities that don't show such as planning, how systematic you are when you work, dedication and perseverance in attacking problems, be them research or administrative or publication related or otherwise.

Comment: Practice. That's probably the only academic advantage. I'm guessing that if you're not publishing papers, hustling for NSF money, teaching a class or being building manager for some campus building, the university doesn't really care.