# What are the reasons that MSE is frequented by professionals?

Tags: discussion

Mathematics Stack Exchange (MSE) is the most unusual blog or wiki I came across. It is frequented by professional mathematicians. The standard is a lot higher than Wikipedia. What makes them willing to spend their effort there? Why MSE is attractive to them? I ask these questions as a layman.

Comment: We like to show off.

Comment: You can find some related discussions here on meta: [Why do *you* answer questions on math.stackexchange?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12991), [What do you really like about working with/contributing to math-SE?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2075), [Academic advantages of activity on SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22884), maybe also
[What is the Real Use of Reputation?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3609) (You can probably find some similar posts on Meta Stack Exchange and Meta StackOverflow.)

Comment: Since you have specifically mentioned Wikipedia, I will add this link: [Comparison of Stack Exchange and Wikipedia?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30707). Also Pete L. Clark's answer here is worth reading: [Questions concerning editing of Wikipedia articles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2771#2778). I know of several reputable mathematicians who are also active Wikipedia editors.

Comment: It's neither a blog nor a wiki.

Comment: Maybe because there is no other reliable forum (excluding AOPS) where users personal info is not used for profit

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I apologise that I failed to classify MSE with mathematical precision. 8-)

Comment: I think it's because they like math.

Comment: I cannot speak for professional mathematicians as I am not one, but the primary reason for spending time here is that it is very rewarding (not in terms of rep points) in terms of variety of topics and questions. Even an expert in a field has a chance to get some new viewpoints.

Comment: I don't think one can get this kind of diversity in a typical classroom scenario. Usually the scope is limited by the designed syllabus and prescribed textbooks. It's like teaching or studying in multiple universities at the same time .

Comment: Call it the  love of association of the mathematical kind...or anchor a down slide of  the rusting mind... at least it rhymes.

Comment: Don’t underestimate the allure of accumulating internet points. Math is just the only way some of us know how to do so.

Comment: Change that to : why is Math Stack Exchange frequented by *anybody studying math*? It is simple : does MSE have any duplicate sites? No. It is priceless, a rarity of the highest order. Add to that the fact that you are getting a repository of results and explanations, from middle-to-high school math all the way up to recent research and explained papers for the cost of your internet connection, and this is the most accessible, maybe only mathematics *community* site, where you can have 100 reputation and get to see the answers of Noam Elkies and Yuval Peres.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: there is a hidden cost however. Apart from the 100 reps you will need a reasonable mathematical background to understand what those people say about elliptic curves. The topic is related to my own interests but unfortunately there are many roadblocks in my way of enjoying the pleasure of elliptic curves. Maybe someday...

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, some day. But mathematical knowledge is the only roadblock, and if such a user asked for clarification I'm sure Noam, Yuval or anyone else reading those comments will be kind enough to attempt a simpler explanation, one mentioning the basic idea and mathematical thought involved but skipping the details. At least I love doing that nowadays!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: yeah that's the best part. If you are willing to learn there is no end to what can be done here.

Comment: Eventually as most of the easy questions get answered and solved here only harder puzzles and weirder questions will remain, and at some point this forum will start to look like mathoverflow but filled with more amateurs hyperfocused on "non mainstream" sub topics/elementary accessible topics.

Comment: The "feel good" attitude of this is quite amusing, but was to be expected: anything critical would be downvoted into oblivion, this is meta, after all. Fortunately, there are honest contributions, too: yes, we like to show off. I think I'm qualified as "professional", even though I wasn't doing maths as a day job in the last 20+ years (but holding some academic degrees in that area). Whatever, the annoying things here are are homework questions, backstabbing (malevolent/revenge downvotes) and the arrogance of power. Now forward, cowards, you can't downvote a comment, but flag, delete, suspend!

Comment: [not being a professional so speculating] There is a community here which enjoys mathematics and always the prospect of an interesting question or angle. Also there is visible record of how people learn mathematics as they get better at asking questions or responding to comments

Comment: Mathematical and scientific knowledge is expanding so rapidly that we have a major pedagogical problem: to help people efficiently learn and deeply understand a vast amount of material.  I'd say the dream is that by contributing to math.stackexchange we can make it much easier for people to learn math. This is already true -- many times I've understood a math idea much more clearly by reading explanations on math.stackexchange. It's so valuable, and it's important to keep it going and keep the knowledge alive.

Comment: I'm not a professional, but I'm on MSE partly because I like the interesting problems and trying to solve them. There's no other place that has this to such an extent.

Comment: Since I took Mr. Jacobson's tenth grade geometry class in 1966, I have been in love with the process of understanding mathematics. I have been blessed with a variety of jobs that involved using and doing mathematics and, now, I have reached that point where my elevator no longer goes all the way to the top any more. The MSE problems that I can still solve are getting lesser and my communication skills are not that great any more. But I love being here and I hope I can go on for a few years more.

Comment: @stevengregory Do not underestimate the power of MSE : you don't need to *hope* to go on for a few years, you will be dragged through by the charisma of the site. Your contributions and insight will be honey to the newer users. Keep going!

Answer (score 32):

Academics have a lot of unstructured time (I do not mean "free" time), which is definitely a part of it. This does not explain why the math should be different from other subject-specific-and-academia-adjacent SEs.

Mathematicians don't need to know where a problem comes from in order to care about it.  That makes math unusually amenable to Internet forums.  In many fields, something is only interesting if a lot of people are talking about it, or if the people talking about it are "important."  If I come up with a question or proposal about how to change a law, for example, who cares; if a retired head of government has the same proposal, it's interesting - because of where it's coming from. Yet if some important person has a position on X, it's well ventilated elsewhere, and an Internet forum is kind of redundant. There are better outlets. This might explain why political scientists and heads of state are not browsing the Politics SE for things to respond to.  Which is not to say that professional mathematicians browse Math.SE for research ideas, but you get the point.

Math has less nexus to things people see in headlines, or hold as personal beliefs.  Random people aren't going to jump into math forums and demand debate (most of the time).  There are people who want their homework done, but that's about it. In many fields, random people form strong opinions about issues after watching TV.  Not in math.  (People complain about a lack of mathematical literacy in the public, but it's part of what keeps a site like this a place where professionals may still appear.)

I'd further note math is not an IP-intensive area. Many of my friends in biology, chemistry, etc. have ties to commercial concerns that either forbid them from publicly sharing anything resembling what they're working on (or might work on).  Many lab sciences folks absorb (rightly or wrongly) a norm that many things are a competition and knowledge is to be shared at most in publications and at conferences.  Not math (although should you work for a government that employs mathematicians, I do not recommend bringing insights or problems from work to Math.SE or indeed anywhere on the Internet).

Math more than many other fields is close to childhood play. Very few people write long essays or lines of code at the behest of other people (or whatever else) as children. But many have fond memories of figuring math things out at an early age. For many this site is a bit like time traveling. And nostalgia aside, math produces problems capable of being understood and posed by very young people that remain of interest to professionals. I can't think of another field like that.

Comment: +1 for comparing math with other professions.

Answer (score 13):

To add to the already excellent answers here, there are two reasons why I personally have contributed to MSE:

1. MSE is an endless source of interesting mathematical problems.  I find problem solving fun, and after one moves beyond things like math competitions, it can be hard to find random math problems to solve on a daily basis.  MSE provides that.  I even have published some stuff that originated from MSE questions.
2. The way the rep and bounty system is structured on MSE make it advantageous to contribute answers to the site even if all you really want is to have a question of your own answered.  The reason I first started contributing answers was to gain rep so I could offer a bounty on a question of mine.  (I am now well past the point where I need rep to offer bounties, so this point doesn't really apply to me any more.  But the bounty system can offer an incentive for people to begin contributing in the first place.)

Answer (score 12):

Similar to a coach of a nationally ranked football team having a recruiting advantage.  For a variety of reasons, mathSE attracted high quality queries and high quality answers, perhaps partly as a result of [mathSE prioritizing this metaMath article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Anyway, math professionals start flocking and giving high quality contributions, which attracts more math professionals.  These additional professionals do the same, which creates an avalanche effect.

It has gotten to the point that it is very common for a mathSE reviewer with a 30+k reputation to leave a *comment* that has more insight/elegance than an **answer** that I *would* have left.

Comment: Agreed.  "mathSE attracted high quality queries and high quality answers"  And, of course, to keep it this way we all should do our part to avoid mathSE from being swamped with "do my homework for me" type  problems.

Comment: @GEdgar While I think that your viewpoint has a great deal of merit, I think that there is also merit in being of value to the query posters.  As a starting point for discussion, see [this list of defects](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33184/downvoting-posts-that-are-very-popular-but-not-especially-good-is-this-an-acce/33211#33211).  I do not subscribe to the one-size-fits-all perspective of requiring (for example) that *significant* work be shown.  ...see next comment

Comment: @GEdgar While this requirement is *generally* reasonable, it depends on the nature of the query and the backgrd of the poster.
For a blatant example where I disagreed, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040627/my-daughter-needs-help-and-i-am-stuck-as-well/4040633#4040633).  There is also a more subtle problem.  Giving priority to quality over service
leads to a culture of anonymous downvoting and rapid voting to close, both of which I object to.   ...see next comment

Comment: @GEdgar I certainly acknowledge the
counter argument that preserving quality leads to greater service.  I simply feel that the situation is actually 
extremely complicated.
At the same time that most posters are seduced by the *path of least resistance*, so are a significant number of 
downvoters - voters to close.

Comment: +1 there and I hope the comments do not become debate about context and effort.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a professional but I've been on this site for a year now and I think my long stay boils down to five points and I can imagine a similar experience would be for someone who is a professional:

- There is a minimum standard kept on questions and answers
- Once written posts can be referenced many times later on another posts, so you kinda build links between concepts in your mind
- There is no other worthy competitor to this site that I know of
- Addiction. This is a point I don't like bringing up but it is indeed true, there is a motivation to hit an X point bench mark on the site, right now I wish to get at least 4000 points.
- Though the site has some addictive nature with the points and all, it is a 'good' addiction as I have learned a lot of things from spending time here. So, it's time well spent.

However, there are negative points about this site too. I think there is a lot more potential for growth and improvement.

Comment: +1 for having brought to light the "addiction" part. There have been times I blocked MSE on my phone cause I spent too much time here. Sometimes it's hard to see a very cool problem you think you can solve and just pass; it's much more common to spend one hour scribbling and hour texxing :)

Comment: Congratulations on 4000 points :)

Comment: Thank you @Blue!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

I started using math.se as an undergrad when I was just starting to explore research-level material that I had noone to ask about. There wasn't really anywhere else where people with expertise would humor me, and what I wanted to know about wasn't in books. I became connected to the community, and after a while, I learned enough that I could start answering questions within my niche. That eventually lead me down a pipeline to math grad school.

I think this experience is unique to math.se and I like the idea that others could have it too. I stick around because I like supporting that.